# Status bar moving down when open collapsing toolbar (with parallax image effect)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with collapsing toolbar layout. I would like to create collapsing toolbar with parallax effect. I read a lot of tutorials and everything is ok except one little element. The background of status bar is  moving down while scrolling NestedScrollView quickly. I would like to create profile like in Facebook app.

I am attaching a video which shows my problem (in this video I am showing borders of layouts).

URL: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RXhEW4244DvsKE3p3dYaIyi5g17PuFP2

Also this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorRedThemePrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/drawer_top_part" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_rules_info_text" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Could you help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: Google helps me.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72450172

Comment: I have a similar problem and I found that this happens when using nestedScrollView as the content. by using a recyclerView it doesn't happen again!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it turns out that it was because of the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` property on the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` element.

If you remove that, it should work.

Here is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/risotto">

                </ImageView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I will try your code in my new project. But I reported this bug to Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72450172 but until now it hasn't been repaired ;(.